# Can we conclude from $V=\ker(T) \oplus\operatorname{im}(T)$ the invariance of both subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis

Can we conclude for an endomorphism $V \in \operatorname{End}(V)$ where V is a finite dimensional vector space from $V=\ker(T) \oplus \operatorname{im}(T)$ that nullspace and image are invariant subspaces?

I somehow "feel" that this should be true, but I am not sure though!

Comment: If, by an invariant subspace $W$, you mean $T(x)\in W$ whenever $x\in W$, then certainly this is true, without the assumption of the direct sum. Since $T(\text{Im}(T))\subset T(V)=\text{Im}(T)$ and $T(\text{Ker}(T))=\{0\}$. Per chance you mean something otherwise?

Comment: @YACP Because, when I started writing the comment, the answer did not appear yet. And I did not find that answer until you point it out. So thanks for that. Maybe I shall delete that post?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $T$ is any linear application you always have $T(\ker T) = \{0\} \subset \ker T$ and $T(\operatorname{Im}(T))\subset T(V) = \operatorname{Im}(T)$.

Comment: so you are saying that both subspaces are always invariant?

Comment: Yes, if $W$ invariant means $T(W)\subset W$.

Answer (score 3):

If $S,T$ are endomorphisms of a vector space $V,$ and we have $ST = TS,$ then both ${\rm ker} S$ and ${\rm Im} S$ are $T$-invariant.
For if $v \in {\rm ker S},$ we have $Sv = 0$ and so $ 0 = T(Sv) = (TS)v = (ST)v = S(Tv).$
Hence $Tv \in {\rm ker S}.$
Similarly , if $w \in {\rm Im}S,$ say $w = Su,$ then $Tw = T(Su) = (TS)u = (ST)u = S(Tu)$ and $Tw \in {\rm Im}S.$
In particular, when $S = T,$ we certainly have the commuting condition, so we may conclude that ${\rm Im}T$ and ${\rm ker}T$ are both $T$-invariant subspaces.